# null pointer exception while trying to read from .xls file apache poi

Tags: java, selenium, automation, apache-poi

```
private static HSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;

private static HSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;

private static HSSFCell Cell;

private static HSSFRow Row;

private  static String[][] getTableArray(String FilePath, String SheetName)    throws Exception

{   

    FileInputStream ExcelFile = null;
    String[][] tabArray = null;

   try{

       ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(FilePath);

       // Access the required test data sheet

       ExcelWBook = new HSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);

       ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);

       int startCol = 1;

       int ci=0;

       int totalRows = ExcelWSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

       int totalCols = ExcelWSheet.getRow(1).getLastCellNum(); 
       System.out.println(totalRows);

       System.out.println(totalCols);
        tabArray=new String[totalRows][totalCols];
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
           for (int j=1;j<=totalRows;j++, ci++)

           {
               //totalCols = ExcelWSheet.getRow(j).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
               //tabArray=new String[totalRows][totalCols];
               int cj=0;
               for (int l = 1; l < totalCols;l++, cj++) {
                //tabArray[ci][cj] = getCellData(j, l);
                 Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(j).getCell(l);

                 String CellData = formatter.formatCellValue(Cell);
                 System.out.println(CellData);

                 tabArray[ci][cj] = CellData;

                System.out.println(j);
                System.out.println(l);
                System.out.println(tabArray[ci][cj]);
                System.out.println("tabArray["+ci+"]["+cj+"]: "+tabArray[ci][cj]);
            }


           }
           System.out.println(tabArray);
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e)

    {

        System.out.println("Could not read the Excel sheet");

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    catch (IOException e)

    {

        System.out.println("Could not read the Excel sheet");

        e.printStackTrace();

    }finally {

        ExcelFile.close();
    }

    return tabArray;

}
```

///// Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(j).getCell(l); here where its throwing null pointer exception.

coloumns heading are TestCases,Enquiry ID, Sl No., Material

need to read from the 2nd column Enquiry ID only and pass one by one in data driven framework.

want to read enquiry ids from excel and pass it to my @test method

Comment: Arrays in Java are Zero base. You have your start your Loop at Zero.

Comment: May be, here should be `for (int j=1; j < totalRows; j++, ci++)`?

Comment: @AutomatingAngularjs Provide more information: 1. What are your exact testing steps?

Comment: Thank you every one for your response, The reason was it was trying to write to a cell which does not exist, the problem was with my loop.